# Safe storing/creating passwords

Tags: passwords, password-protection, change-password

We are writing new applications and in requirements there are some rules about passwords:

1. cannot contain 6 repeated pharses in a
       row
2. cannot be the same as last 6 passwords

Second point is easy because we have hashes of this passwords but how can we check 6 repeated pharses?

Example:

first password: kotek123

second password: kot453

how can I check subsequence if I just have hash of this passwords? Is it even possible?
How work masked passwords, I mean when password is kotek123 then some banks just want k#t##23 to log in? Do they store hashes of all possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps, you should store all subsequences and check if any of them have occured in the previous six passwords. 
So it's possible, but very uncomfortable for clients and for developers as well . I wouldn't like to use such a system.
Recently we had the same problem in our system, but we didn't want to poison our lives, so we check similarity of last and new password. It looks simple to do, because, usually,  when user wants to change the password, he have to give both passwords, last and new. 
I'm curious what method you will apply

Comment: We will do exactly the same - comparing subsequences only with last password and store last six hashes to check if user don't want to set the same again.

Comment: Maybe we'll generate similar password hashes - if someone password is password1 then generate password2, password3 and check if hashes are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, if you only have the hash value. This is exactly the goal of hashing a password.

By the way, in the example, the passwords are very different. I recomend just using long passwords, with special characters, and check that on the password creation.

I think masked passwords just store some characters in the database

Comment: There are also requirements for special characters and so on but I just skipped it to make example clear. 
How can I check if password are really different if I just have hashes?
I don't think that masked passwords stores anything in plaintext - that would reveal informations about password